# Maven Plugin Project cannot use expression to inject MavenSession or MavenProject

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am trying to build my own maven plugin project.
I follow the instructions here on the [Office Site](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/index.html).

I want to use `MavenSession` and `MavenProject` in my `Mojo`. 
Here is the code snippet:

```java
@Mojo(name = "execute-assembly", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PACKAGE, requiresDependencyCollection =
        ResolutionScope.RUNTIME)
public class ExecuteAssemblyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter(defaultValue= "${session}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MavenSession mavenSession;

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${session}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MavenSession session;

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MavenProject mavenProject;

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MavenProject project;

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${repositorySystemSession}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private RepositorySystemSession repositorySystemSession;
```

I find the [Evaluator for plugin parameters expressions](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.html), but none of them can be injected. All of them are `null` when I debug into the `execute` method.

Comment: First question. Why are you writing a plugin? For what purpose? Second you have MavenSession as well as MavenProject duplicate only one is necessary.  Furthermore how are you debugging ? Those parameters are injected by Maven during an execution of the plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you anyway. MavenProject and MavenSession is duplicated for test, and it should not affect the injection. About debug, you can refer to the [Maven Plugin Testing](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/index.html).

Comment: Does not make sense to duplicate for test. I never use harness for testing (can you point where it is documented to duplicate for tests?) Apart from that you haven not answered my questions?

Comment: @khmarbaise Not matter if it is duplicated, actually I tried both, none of them can be injected, so this is the main point. After searching and read the source code, this problem of injection maybe cause by the version of [Maven Plugin Tools Java Annotations](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/dependency-management.html). The maven dependency of the plugin is ```3.0```, but when I change to this version, new error occurred. I am really tired to guess how to write the correct ```Parameter``` to injection. I just migrate my plugin from maven to gradle.

Comment: @khmarbaise I keep the plugin project, just in case you or someone else can help me about the injection. In my opinion, this problem due to the maven dependency version.

Comment: You seemed to ignore my question. As I mentioned the injection will be done during the Maven run...and you have not answered how you tried to debug it ? How you run it etc. Then simply sorry without informations I can't help....